# My.Settings not saving variables

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form2

Dim strInitialDirectory As String
Dim strInitialFile As String
Const strDefaultFileDirectory As String = "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Visual Basic\Test"
Const strDefaultFileName As String = "\test.txt"
Dim strFileJPath1 As String = strInitialDirectory + strInitialFile
Dim strFileJPath2 As String = strDefaultFileDirectory + strDefaultFileName

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If My.Settings.strInitialDirectory = Nothing Or My.Settings.strInitialFile = Nothing Then
        My.Settings.strInitialDirectory = strDefaultFileDirectory
        My.Settings.strInitialFile = strDefaultFileName
    Else
        MsgBox("Else executed") ' debug 
        strInitialDirectory = strDefaultFileDirectory
        strInitialFile = strDefaultFileName
        strInitialDirectory = My.Settings.strInitialDirectory
        strInitialFile = My.Settings.strInitialFile
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Basically, when the form loads I'd like it to check if there is anything in My.Settings and if not, set the values to the defaults, however upon opening the program again, it does not execute the else statement, leaving me to believe I'm doing something wrong and the settings aren't saving. Any input into this? Thanks.

Comment: At the end of the load event add a My.Settings.Save

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to call the save function in My.Settings

```vb
My.Settings.Save()
```

You should add this at the end of an update settings function. This will save all the settings for the next session.

Here us an example of an UpdateSettings function:

```vb
Private Sub UpdateSettings()

    Console.WriteLine("Saving Settings")

    My.Settings.WO_imprevu = CheckBoxImprevu.Checked
    My.Settings.WO_prevu = CheckBoxPrevu.Checked
    My.Settings.Date_type = ComboBoxDateType.SelectedIndex
    My.Settings.Date_debut = DateTimePickerDebut.Value

    My.Settings.Save()

    Console.WriteLine("Settings Saved")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` instead of `= Nothing`.

Change your sub to this:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(My.Settings.strInitialDirectory) OrElse String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(My.Settings.strInitialFile) Then
        My.Settings.strInitialDirectory = strDefaultFileDirectory
        My.Settings.strInitialFile = strDefaultFileName
    Else
        MsgBox("Else executed") ' debug 
        strInitialDirectory = strDefaultFileDirectory
        strInitialFile = strDefaultFileName
        strInitialDirectory = My.Settings.strInitialDirectory
        strInitialFile = My.Settings.strInitialFile
    End If
End Sub
```